# Conditional Not Being Hit - Conditionally Rendering React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure why no matter if isAuthenticated is false or not, it always ends up rendering  instead of hitting the .  When isAuthenticated is false you'd think it would obviously hit the redirect but it's not.

```
class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(`ProtectedRoute: isAuthenticated: ${this.props.isAuthenticated}`)
    const ComponentToRender = this.props.component,
    RouteToRender = (
      <Route
        {...this.props}
        render={() =>
          (this.props.isAuthenticated ? (<ComponentToRender {...this.props} />) :
            (<Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: {from: this.props.location
                }}}
            />))}
      />)

      return (RouteToRender)
  }
}
```

Here's what I see for RouteToRender in WebStorm when I debug:
[image]

What I did is to just force a redirect and I noticed that I also had to remove the {...this.props} and the state: {from: this.props.location} and this worked:

```
class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(`ProtectedRoute: isAuthenticated: ${this.props.isAuthenticated}`)
    const ComponentToRender = this.props.component,
    RouteToRender = (
      <Route
        render={() =>
          (<Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login'
              }}
           />)}
      />)

      return (RouteToRender)
  }
```

So it might be an issue with the fact that I'm inheriting props.  So here's what the call looks like that utilizes this component:

```
<ProtectedRoute component={DashboardContainer} path='/dashboard' />
```

So I am receiving those props too incoming... (component and path)

**THE FIX**:

```
<Route
          render={({this.props}) =>
            (this.props.isAuthenticated ? (<ComponentToRender {...this.props} />) :
              (<Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: '/login',
                  state: {from: this.props.location
                  }}}
              />))}
        />)
```

Actually it doesn't fix it totally, but at least it's not rendering the component if !isAuthenticated.  But now my last changed caused another problem, if isAuthenticated is true, it's not rendering the  probably because  no longer has a path since I removed {...this.props} from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending both the component and render as props to Route component. Since component prop is available, the Route renders that component instead of triggering the render.

Comment: well I'm trying to mimic the PrivateRoute function here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow